# in R, converting for loop to apply for efficiency

Tags: r, for-loop, nlp, apply

I am doing some NLP and trying to find common 2-grams out of a specific (limited) corpus.  I have written a for loop that does what I want, but it takes a long time to run on any real amount of data.  I feel like I should be able to do this with apply but I cannot for the life of me figure out how.  Any help is much appreciated.

I've tokenized and ngram'ed the corpus into the following data frames (this is obviously just a small subset for example's sake).

```
tk
     word Freq
5477 with  186
1998  for  182
2644   it  179
3482   on  174
5354  was  168

ng
        ngrams Freq   w1   w2 rate
2434    at the   30   at  the    0
16027 with the   29 with  the    0
140     <> But   28   <>  But    0
223      <> He   28   <>   He    0
6885    I have   28    I have    0
```

I have the following for loop that works on these two data frames:

```
for(i in 1:dim(ng)[1]) {
    tkw1 <- ifelse(length(tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w1[i]]) > 0, 
                   tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w1[i]], 0)
    tkw2 <- ifelse(length(tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w2[i]]) > 0,
                   tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w2[i]], 0)
    dnm <- tkw1 + tkw2
    dnm <- ifelse(dnm >= 1, dnm, ng$Freq[i])
    ng$rate[i] <- ng$Freq[i] / dnm
}
```

The idea is to compute a "rate" for each row which is essentially the number of times the 2-gram appears, divided by (the sum of) the number of times each word appears individually.  The for loop does this, but it's very slow when used on a large scale.

Sidenote: there are some ifelse statements which were necessary to debug the fact that sometimes (because of imperfect preprocessing) one of the words in the 2-gram doesn't match a word in the tk data frame.

Sooo, is there a way to do this with apply (or maybe sapply or tapply)?  I've been working on it for hours and hours and I can't figure it out.
Thanks!

In case this helps, my most recent attempt was:

```
TGrate <- function(ng, w1, w2, Freq){
    tkw1 <- ifelse(length(tk$Freq[tk$word==w1]) > 0, 
           tk$Freq[tk$word==w1], 0)
    tkw2 <- ifelse(length(tk$Freq[tk$word==w2]) > 0,
           tk$Freq[tk$word==w2], 0)
    dnm <- tkw1 + tkw2
    dnm <- ifelse(dnm >= 1, dnm, Freq)
    rate <- as.numeric(Freq) / as.numeric(dnm)
    rate
}
ng$rate <- apply(ng, 1, TGrate, w1="w1", w2="w2", Freq="Freq")
```

but this just produces a bunch of NAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which is faster (if they are even better than a for loop), but I have two ways to go about it. They both get the "dnm" and then calculate the rate separately.

The first is with merge:

```
names(tk)[2] <- 'tkfreq'
ng <- merge(ng,tk,by.x = 'w1',by.y = 'word',all.x = T)
ng <- merge(ng,tk,by.x = 'w2',by.y = 'word',all.x = T)
ng$tkfreq.x[is.na(ng$tkfreq.x)] <- 0
ng$tkfreq.y[is.na(ng$tkfreq.y)] <- 0
ng$dnm <- ng$tkfreq.x + ng$tkfreq.y
```

The second is with apply:

```
ng$dnm <- apply(ng,1,function(x){
  sum(tk[tk$word %in% x[c('w1','w2')],'Freq'])
})
```

And they both end with this to get the final rate:

```
ng$rate <- ng$Freq / ng$dnm
ng[is.infinite(ng$rate),'rate'] <- 1
```

The apply version is concise and IMO, easier to understand. That said, a for loop is often faster. There are lots of ways to pull different parts out and vectorize , but the best solution likely depends on your data. You might want to subset those that actually have matches, or you might want parallel processing on the apply function. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't speak for the apply example, but: the reason why your loop appears to be so slow is that you're writing to a data.frame in each iteration.

Data.frames are non-primitive objects, and have copy-on-modify semantics. To put that in human: every time you tweak a data.frame what you're actually doing is finding memory for the "new" data.frame, creating a copy in that space, assigning the old name to the copy, and deleting the old object.

Unsurprisingly, when this is done in a loop - i.e., potentially thousands or tens of thousands or millions of times - it's incredibly slow. One answer is to use packages like [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) or [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html), which have pretty good approaches to iterating on subsets of data.frames, but the first tactic tried should be investigating whether you actually need to be writing to the data.frame each iteration. In this case, you don't: you're producing a single value for a single field. So why not write to a vector, which has different behaviour on modification, and then add that vector to the data.frame at the end?

```
#Create a vector to hold the output. If we make sure it's the length of the
#actual output, it never has to be copied when modified.
holding <- numeric(nrow(ng))

for(i in 1:dim(ng)[1]) {
    tkw1 <- ifelse(length(tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w1[i]]) > 0, 
               tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w1[i]], 0)
    tkw2 <- ifelse(length(tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w2[i]]) > 0,
               tk$Freq[tk$word==ng$w2[i]], 0)
    dnm <- tkw1 + tkw2
    dnm <- ifelse(dnm >= 1, dnm, ng$Freq[i])

    #Write to the vector
    holding[i] <- ng$Freq[i] / dnm
}

#And now add the vector to the df
ng$rate <- holding
```

That should speed things up quite a bit. One other important thing to look at, though, is how you're referencing elements from data.frames within the loop. As [Hadley notes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html#why-is-r-slow) (see the section "Extracting a single value from a data frame"), due to a lack of language optimisation you can get startlingly different performance costs from different ways of accessing the same value.

Comment: Thanks.  I never knew that about using data frames inside loops.  Very helpful.